# OpenDkim-testkey record not found

Tags: opendkim

trying this command after install opendkim and postfix

```
 opendkim-testkey -d aan-tsu.info  -s default -v -v -v 

   opendkim-testkey: checking key 'default._domainkey.aan-tsu.info' opendkim-
  testkey: 'default._domainkey.aan-tsu.info' record not found
```

I have the following record in my bind dns zone file

```
default._domainkey 14400 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCtQ0IgCVq6Z0B7pQQYZWmVcMpWJNeRFkfVF9qOSkBFyLEG8pRoUuZrAMeAfMqWT1wPkJ+vvdWxCJP8yzY0wHM10ePGazonKozoh4stCLR54dixtgrHZGPXG+Ogtei16kPkJXe7jZXzCmHQHMOAS95KoWSomEnDAXwTy33h0lZrmQIDAQAB"
```

my opendkim.conf file looks like

```
AutoRestart             Yes
AutoRestartRate         10/1h
LogWhy                  Yes
Syslog                  Yes
SyslogSuccess           Yes
Mode                    sv
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
KeyTable                refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256
Socket                  inet:8891@localhost
PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
UMask                   022
UserID                  opendkim:opendkim
TemporaryDirectory      /var/tmp
```

why always get no record found

Answer (score 2):

Because wherever you stuck that DNS record isn't the delegated authoritative server for the zone:

```
$ dig default._domainkey.aan-tsu.info TXT

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> default._domainkey.aan-tsu.info TXT
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 23507
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;default._domainkey.aan-tsu.info. IN    TXT

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
aan-tsu.info.       3576    IN  SOA ns1.centos-webpanel.com. emd-lb.outlook.com. 2013071600 86400 7200 3600000 86400
```

(Or you didn't reload BIND after making the change, or any one of a number of other possible reasons, none of which we can even start to guess at because there's no details of your DNS setup or what you did)